# Windows 8 Activation behind a proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-8-preview, windows-activation

How to activate windows 8 behind the college proxy server? `Error code : 0x8004fe33`
I've tried `netsh winhttp` to configure the system proxy but no success.

Comment: To me, using MSDN Windows 8 Enterprise, I needed to do command-line activation like so: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/08/24/tip-of-the-day-microsoft-windows-8-enterprise-activation-itpro-windows8.aspx#.UIA5yhzn-Ul

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of that error code is a proxy requiring basic authentication but not configured to whitelist some specific URLS needed for activation. The suggested work-around for the user (in opposition to the proxy owner) is to use phone activation, by running "slui 4".

Comment: Thanks. I finally did it by running internet via my phone connection.